# How can i update component data from other component in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dashboard component which remains the same for all pages and a load component one of the other components which changes according to router-outlet. I want to hide manage load button in dashboard components if I delete all loads in manage load component. I am stuck at it even after google search. Any help will be appreciated.
here is my dashboard component HTML file

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 side-nav">
                <div class="panel">
                    <div class="welcome">
                        <img src="assets/img/welcome.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#side-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="side-navbar">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked btn-collpase panel_show collapse in">
                                    <li routerLinkActive="active">
                                        <a href=""  routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li routerLinkActive="active">
                                        <a href="" routerLink="/dashboard/postLoad">Post Load</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li *ngIf="this.loads.length > 0">
                                        <a href="" routerLink="/dashboard/manageLoad">Manage Loads</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <!-- why-us-setion end -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

and here is dashboard component ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {TruckService} from "../services/truck.service";
    import {LoadService} from "../services/load.service";
    import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-dashboard',
        templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
    })
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
        loads  = [];
        constructor(private loadService:LoadService) { }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.loadService.getLoads().subscribe(data=>{
                this.loads = data;
                console.log("load data is "+data);
            });
        }

    }
```

Here is manage load HTML file

```
<div *ngIf="loads.length > 0">
<h3>Your Loads</h3>
<table class="table-responsive table-stripped table-bordered tab" width="90%;">
    <thead style="text-align: center;">
    <tr style="padding: 5px;">
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Weight</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr style="height: 40px;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;" *ngFor="let load of loads">
        <td style="">{{load.from_name}}</td>
        <td>{{load.to_name}}</td>
        <td>{{getLoadWeight(load.truck_capacity_id)}}</td>
        <td>{{ toDate(load.posted_at)}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" routerLink="/dashboard/viewTrucks/{{load.id}}">View Trucks</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteLoad(load.id)">Delete Load</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is manage to load component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {LoadService} from "../../services/load.service";
    import {TruckService} from "../../services/truck.service";
    import {AlertService} from "../../services/alert.service";
    import {NavigationExtras, Router} from "@angular/router";

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-manage-load',
      templateUrl: './manage-load.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./manage-load.component.css']
    })
    export class ManageLoadComponent implements OnInit {
        loads  = [];
        loadWeights = [];
       //  myload;

        constructor(private loadService:LoadService,private truckService:TruckService,private alertService:AlertService,private router:Router) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.loadService.getLoads().subscribe(data=>{
          this.loads = data;
          console.log("load data is "+data);
          });
        this.truckService.getTruckCapacity().subscribe(data=>{
            console.log("load weights are "+JSON.stringify(data));
            this.loadWeights = data;
        });
      }

      getLoadWeight(id){
         let weight:String = "";
           this.loadWeights.map(function(item) {
              if(item.id == id){
                  console.log("this weight is "+item.name);
                  weight =  item.name;
              }
          });
          return weight;
      }

      toDate(date){
          let hdate = new Date(date);
          let mytime = hdate.getDate() + '/' + (hdate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + hdate.getFullYear();
          return mytime;
      }
        deleteLoad(id){
          this.loadService.deleteLoad(id).subscribe(data=>{
              if(data['status'] == "success"){
                  this.loadService.getLoads().subscribe(data=> {
                      this.loads = data;
                  });
                this.alertService.alertSuccess(data['message'],'');
              }else if(data['status'] == "error"){
                  this.alertService.alertError(data['message'],'');
              }
          });
        }


    }
```

in case you need load service file here it is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

    @Injectable()
    export class LoadService {

        constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
        }

        getLoads(){
            return this.http.get("http://localhost:3002/load/get-loads")
                .catch(this.getLoadsErrorHandler)
        }
        getLoadsErrorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse) {
            return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");
        }

        deleteLoad(id){
            return this.http.delete("http://localhost:3002/load/delete-load?id="+id)
                .catch(this.deleteLoadErrorHandler)
        }
        deleteLoadErrorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse) {
            return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");
        }
        getCurrentLoad(id){
            return this.http.get("http://localhost:3002/load/get-current-load?id="+id).map(response => response)
                .catch(this.getCurrentLoadErrorHandler)
        }
        getCurrentLoadErrorHandler(error:HttpErrorResponse) {
            return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");
        }

    }
```

Any help would be highly appereciated.

Comment: TL;DR, but... https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. And I can clearly see that you are fetching loads in dashboard component from database by hitting service. There is no way that you update one component data in another component since other component is not loaded yet.
So you can do something like, hit that fetch load service after every 5 seconds.
So when you will update from manage loads component, when you come in dashboard component it will fetch new data and after every 5 seconds it will fetch a updated data from db.

You can use Anonymous Subscription for hitting API. In this this you import AnomymousSubscription, create its object then create a set a timer and function a that will hit continuously.

I hope it will help and you will understand a solution.